# How to var dump urls for all posts

Tags: posts, pre-get-posts

I need to see all urls of all publish blog posts in the site. How can I get this?
I want this for redirecting in .htaccess of old site to new site.
This needed in anything page of site.The result is each posts url on a new line.

Comment: This seems rather broad, there are multiple questions being asked here, and no context, or examples of what you've tried, or what is available to you. E.g. would a `wp cli` command be possible? Do you have access to change the code? What problem are you attempting to solve? Please edit your question to provide this information

Comment: Yes, I have access to change the code and I just want to see the urls of all publish posts in my site.

Comment: You still need to provide context, why do you want this? Where do you want this? What format do you want it in? Are you trying to put the data into a speadsheet? **Edit your question**

Comment: I've been edited my question.

Comment: Ah you're redirecting!!! This is an important and super useful piece of information :) Thanks for updating your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been solved my problem by this query:

```
SELECT  `post_name` 
FROM  `wp_posts` 
WHERE  `post_content` IS NOT NULL 
AND  `post_title` IS NOT NULL 
AND  `post_status` =  'publish'
AND  `post_type` =  'post'
```

Comment: Just a SQL tip: you can use "=" instead of "LIKE" since you aren't doing any wildcard matches. This can have significant impacts on performance.

Comment: Thank you, but it's a one-time query.

Comment: Gotcha, just keep it in mind for the future :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following WP CLI command:

```
wp post list --field=url --post_type=post --posts_per_page=-1 --post_status=publish
```

The result is each posts url on a new line